# Studio Environment Template setup

Tags: rendering, import, lighting, template

I do a lot of mechanical design in software packages like, Autodesk Inventor, Solidworks and Catia.

I would like to build a portfolio on the web (in certain cases, my customers also want presentation images for their products), and for that I want to create professionally rendered images of the products / equipment / projects I design.

The product / projects / equipment can vary in physical size quite dramatically (from a few millimeters, to complete factory layouts.

I would like to set up various studio environment templates for blender, where I can import the 3D data from the CAD software, add materials and render in one of the studio environment templates.

Does anyone have advice / suggestions as to where I can find a good workflow for setting up these templates.

I am not a "Blender guy", and more a "CAD guy", so I do not want to have to spend too much time with each render in blender, and therefore think that if I have pre-prepared studio environments where I can "just" drop in the CAD data, add material and render, this could be a workable solution for me.

Thanks
Rob

Comment: When you are referring to templates, do you mean a 3D scene of a studio lighting setup that you can place your product in or is this about the setup of Blender's UI?

Comment: Yes, it is about the 3D scene setup, so that I can place my product into the scene, add some materials (maybe tweak lighting) and render to generate an image. In other words, I do not want to setup cameras, lighting, infinite background etc, etc. for each product I want to render. I want that all in the template, and then just "drop" the product in, tweak and render.